# Strange Lightning Error: "Action failed: aura:if$controller$handleTheTruth"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, spring17

In our Salesforce Lightning components we're running into a very strange error:

`Action failed: aura:if$controller$handleTheTruth [null is not an object (evaluating 'b.Aa')]
Failing descriptor: {aura:if$controller$handleTheTruth}`

I have ran into this bug before and by process of elimination (desperately removing and adding code until I've found the line that causes the error) found that this was because of a `aura:if`. This makes the `handleTheTruth` part a bit more sense.

The `isTrue` statement had two parts (`and(statement, statement)`) and by again adding/removing statements, I found out that both statements worked individually, just not combined. So I then nested the `aura:if`'s and to my surprise, it worked.

Now I'm running into the same error, but it only appears sporadically when modifying the data that is being iterated over. I've removed all the `aura:if`'s in the iteration and it worked, but now it's still giving the error message, no matter how I simplify the statement.

This is the `aura:if` component that throws the error. If I take it off, it works okay.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!centre.isLeadingCC == true || p.pck.PackageType__c == 'Time' || p.pck.PackageType__c == 'Group'}">
```

I have checked the data and it checks out, I have tried just parts of the statement, but any of the three statements will throw the error.

Not sure if its relevant info, but the `aura:if` is nested under two `aura:iterations`.

I have also tried looking into the data, since it says `null is not an object`, but all the data seems to check out and no nulls are to be found.

I am really not sure what is going on, or what the message means. The actual code is quite a bit to post, so I'm wondering if anyone has ran into this error before and know what is going on?

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Comment: So it can't handleTheTruth? That's interesting.

Comment: As described below, handleTheTruth is the controller method called when an aura:if is evaluated to true (obviously this is not part of the public API and could change at any moment). Without more code though, it's hard to say what's the problem: https://twitter.com/GrayJustise/status/852596982971416576

Comment: @FabienTaillon I've added the faulty aura:if and a bit more context on the code. It's a big component so I'm not really sure what parts are most relevant to post.

Comment: try `<aura:if isTrue="{!true == true}">`  - is this ok?

Comment: Yes, try 3 things: test with a basic isTrue formula, try to remove everything from inside your aura:if tag, and try removing your aura:if from the iteration (if you can easily). Do you have a else ?

Comment: I tried something similar in my org and seems to work. Happy to help, but are you able to isolate the problem and provide relevant pieces for us to replicate? Without it we are shooting in the dark.